# Why is 「微笑み選ぼう」 correct in grammar?

Tags: particle-を, song-lyrics

The sentence 微笑み選ぼう is part of the lyrics of a song called [錆びついたマシンガンで今を撃ち抜こう](http://j-lyric.net/artist/a0039c4/l007405.html).

I'm wondering why it is correct in grammar because it seems to me that there is supposed to be a を between 微笑み and 選ぼう.

== Update ==
Here is the shorter version of the song for interpreting the meaning of this sentence: [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HX9evhBKxf4).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is omitted を. We often omit a post-positional particle especially in spoken language.

For example, 本(を)買いに行く, 昨日(は),学校に行った, 明日どこ(へ)行く?, 何(を)食べようか?, etc.

Answer (score 1):

No for 微笑みを選ぼう。　In this case, '微笑み' is not object for choice.

微笑み選ぼう　is more precisely 微笑み、選ぼう。

It means, With smile, choose (trip to uncharted town)!

It is hard to interpret this by grammatical analysis.
Only semantic analysis can get object of choice. I think.

Comment: Not sure if I understand it correctly, but this sentence doesn't seem to be related to the trip to uncharted town. The previous sentence and this sentence together (乾いた夕暮れに 微笑み選ぼう) seem to stand for their own meaning: "In the parched dusk, choose to smile." Here is the shorter version of the song if it can help interpreting the meaning: [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HX9evhBKxf4).

Comment: I think. Usually smile is generated without thinking. But choosing is basically based on thinking.
 Therefore choose smile is quite unnatural.
 Don't you think so?

Comment: @ kmugitani I think 微笑み選ぼう include the meaning like "choosing smile in any situation", so I think it is natural. And If the phrase is 微笑みとともに選ぼう、 it is translated as " choose with smile".

Comment: My opinion is the same as Yuuichi Tam's. And that's why I thought this sentence should be interpreted together with the previous sentence. So maybe in some cases it is somewhat sentimental in the parched dusk, and this sentence encourages people to choose to smile instead of being sentimental.