# What does 家建てる mean?

Tags: meaning, words, colloquial-language, particle-を

I cannot figure out what 「家建てた」 on [this tweet](https://twitter.com/koikekazuo/status/608516615261442048) means.

> 「エレクチオン」で**家建てた**僕の言語能力を舐めちゃいけませン。

Is it a typo for 「打ち立てた」? Or it is a word that Koike Kazuo coined? If so, what does it mean?

I think "made a house" is a little bit strange in the context. (I *know* the particle を is sometimes omitted.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is 「微笑み選ぼう」 correct in grammar?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/34240/why-is-%e5%be%ae%e7%ac%91%e3%81%bf%e9%81%b8%e3%81%bc%e3%81%86-correct-in-grammar)

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/3152/9831

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the guidelines of omitting particles?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/3151/what-are-the-guidelines-of-omitting-particles) (this is the second link suggested above, I think it's more appropriate)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just from reading the Wikipedia article, it seems that using the word エレクチオン can be considered a trademark of Koike Kazuo's writing (as is using *katakana* ン where usual orthography would demand *hiragana* ん).

In the tweet, he is simply saying that he "made a career" out of (using) エレクチオン, so one shouldn't make fun of / underestimate his language abilities.

家（を）建てた literally just means "built a house" and could indeed be taken literal, or as a metaphor for "made a living".

The particle を is often omitted in colloquial speech (here writing).

Comment: So he said he succeeded by his language abilities? Because he is a comic artist (not a writer), the answer seems unreasonable for me...

Comment: @Dim Wikipedia says he is a 漫画原作者、小説家、脚本家、作詞家、作家 (comic artist/writer, novelist, playwright, songwriter and author). In any case, if his writing is known for following a particular style, he doesn't seem to just to draw, but also use language. This is what he seems to refer to in his tweet.

Comment: There are other ways to read 家 that can be useful here: either as "home" or "family".  In this context, I think reading 家を建てる as "build a home" can facilitate understanding how this can be read more broadly as "make a living".